# reset git commit in branch master : fatal: ambiguous argument 'commit': unknown revision or path not in

Tags: git

I want to go to Commit with ID f8d3157 but it shows error:
**git log --oneline:**

```
706b743 (HEAD -> master) api real connect login
f8d3157 Ui regester page
722ec67 Ui Logi page
fa400a0 connect api.js in Home-post
a5a6e68 connect api.js in SideRight
128908f connect  api.js in sideLeft
42c0a87 aad file config  api instance
```

**git reset --hard commit f8d3157**

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'commit': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: The word `commit` is the culprit, it's not expected here. Go for `git reset --hard f8d3157`

Comment: I did not understand.you mean, there is no commit?

Comment: Look closely! You wrote `git reset --hard commit f8d3157` and @RomainValeri suggested `git reset --hard f8d3157`. Now, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: @j6t Sounds like a language issue. Yes, @Mina, `f8d3157` IS a commit, but the command doesn't expect the *word* `commit` here, it's just a syntax thing.

Comment: right!! that was my fault. Wrong typed

Comment: Please do not modify ("correct") your question in a way that the context does not make sense anymore or that invalidates the comments and answers. I have reverted your removal of the word "commit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to go to this specific commit use

```
git checkout f8d3157
```

This will create a detached head, so once here you may use

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name
```

to create a new branch and start working.

Careful ! if you use git reset you're going to lose some of your commit and maybe some uncommited code... here the command :

```
git reset --hard commit f8d3157
```